# Working with Agora for video chat and AR Foundation for Face Tracking effects

Tags: unity3d

Estoy tratando de hacer un video chat con Agora y con AR Foundation para efectos de seguimiento facial.

El problema es que AR Foundation funciona con la cámara de realidad aumentada que se superpone a la cámara Agora.

¿Es posible trabajar con la cámara Agora como cámara AR para Ar Foundation? Creo que tal vez pueda reemplazar la cámara AR de AR Foundation y ponerla los scripts necesarios en la cámara Agora, pero no pude encontrar la cámara Agora en escena.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Hola, Pablo! Recuerda que SOes tiene como idioma el español, por lo que debes traducir toooda tu prgunta -incluyendo el título- a español. Puedes moverla a stackoverflow.com, también, pero tal vez acá podamos ayudarte en español :)

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias por avisar! Estaba seguro que estaba en stackoverflow.com, la traducí a Español por si alguien puede ayudar.